# How to include documentation for unique match cases in macros?

Tags: macros, rust, documentation, documentation-generation, rust-crates

Is is possible to write documentation for individual match cases of an exported macro.

```
/// This macro does stuff // this works
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! macro{
    /// Today it's time for cats // error: no rules expected the token `[`
    (cat) => { ... };
    /// Today it's time for dogs // error: no rules expected the token `[`
    (dog) => { ... };
    /// Why not both // error: no rules expected the token `[`
    (cats and dogs) => { ... };
}
```

Is something like this possible or do I have to do it like this:

```
/// This macro does stuff
/// `(cat)` - Today it's time for cats
/// `(dog)` - Today it's time for dogs
/// `(cats and dogs)` - Why not both
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! macro{
    (cat) => { ... }; 
    (dog) => { ... };
    (cats and dogs) => { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  The only place you can attach documentation to a macro is to the macro as a whole.